# Punctuation at end of sentence for partial question

Tags: grammar

When a question is followed by justification e.g

Could you pass me the jug of water, this soup is really dry

Should you add a full stop/period at the end or a question mark?

Could you pass me the jug of water, this soup is really dry.

Or

Could you pass me the jug of water, this soup is really dry?

Comment: Is it a statement, or a question?

Comment: "Could you pass me the jug of water? This soup is really dry." or "Could you pass me the jug of water (this soup is really dry)?" Or if you can change the order of the words, "This soup is really dry; could you pass me the jug of water?"

Comment: It's not one sentence, as @MrLister has pointed out.